# How to merge rows that has similarities in factor in data frame in R?

Tags: r, rstudio

suppose I have a data frame looking like this:

```
                                        CURRENT_USE  freq
1                                                        31
79                          2 Unit Converted Dwelling    31
83                                    2 Unit Dwelling    31
94                                            2 Units    31
118                                   3 Unit Dwelling    31
231                                         Apartment    31
236                                        Apartment     31
258                                    Apartment Bldg    31
264                                Apartment Building    32
327                                    Apartment Unit    32
354                               Appartment Building    32
363                                               Apt    32
366                                          Apt Bldg    33
369                                      Apt Building    34
377                                              Apt.    34
378                                         Apt. Bldg    35
381                                     Apt. Building    35
392                                             Arena    35
521                                              Bank    35
534                                      Banquet Hall    35
590                                     Bowling Alley    36
666                                          Bungalow    36
705                                    Car Dealership    36
795                                            Church    36
827                                              Club    37
852                                           College    37
879                                        Commercial    37
964                            Commercial/Residential    37
1001                                 Community Centre    38
1013                                   Community Hall    38
1040                                            Condo    38
1075                                      Condominium    38
1120                               Converted Dwelling    38
1138                                  Converted House    38
1150                        Converted House - 2 Units    39
1153                        Converted House - 3 Units    39
1171                        Converted House (2 Units)    39
1181                          Converted House 2 Units    39
1202                         Converted House, 2 Units    40
1204                         Converted House, 3 Units    40
```

How do I merge rows such that my data frame would look like

```
                                         CURRENT_USE  freq
1                                                        31
79                          2 Unit Converted Dwelling    93
118                                   3 Unit Dwelling    31
231                                         Apartment   392
392                                             Arena    35
521                                              Bank    35
534                                      Banquet Hall    35
590                                     Bowling Alley    36
666                                          Bungalow    36
705                                    Car Dealership    36
795                                            Church    36
827                                              Club    37
852                                           College    37
879                                        Commercial    74
1001                                 Community Centre    76
1040                                            Condo    76
1120                               Converted Dwelling   312
```

basically merging rows that has similar names. I assume I can rename every single row to same names and merge them but just wondering if there can a code to do this easier

Comment: You have some rows with `Apartment` some wth `Apt.`  Are those all similar?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aggregate function to return your final summary:

```
X<-data.frame(CURRENT_USE = c("A","B","A","B"), Freq = c(10,12,1,3), stringsAsFactors=F)
X_Out<-aggregate(Freq~CURRENT_USE,data=X, FUN=sum)
```

Standardizing your Current Use column requires more drudgery. The grep family of functions can be useful for these type of tasks. For example if you want to change any value in Current Use that contains the text "Apt" (eg "Apartment ")to "Apartment":

```
X$CURRENT_USE[grepl("Apt", X$CURRENT_USE)]<-"Apartment"
```